# string is contain with newline symbol (\n), how to use regex to replace \n to \n?

Tags: python

I have a single string

```
test = " \n this \nis\n\nto learn \n\n\n regex \n in \n\n python."
```

I used re.sub to find and replace \n to \n but it's not working out

```
check = re.sub("\n", "\n", test)
```

expected result:

```
this 
is 
to 
learn
regex
in 
python
```

there is another option to do the same as above but if I compare to time consumption then regex will win

another option

```
# I need to loop through every single word in the string plus it doesn't change 
  if I have data like this "\nthis\n\nis" 

check = test.replace("\n", "\n")
```

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? `\n` is just how newlines are represented in the `repr` of a string, but they're already actual newlines; what you're doing is a no-op. Just use `print(test)` and you'll see the actual newlines rendered.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Look closely.  Sometimes words are separated by multiple `\n`, along with spaces as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: That's what they show, but it's not what they asked for in either the code or the prose describing their intent. Thus the request for clarification.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I want to read line by line later

Answer (score 3):

You may try replacing all whitespace `\s+` with `\n`:

```
test = " \n this \nis\n\nto learn \n\n\n regex \n in \n\n python."
output = re.sub(r'\s+', '\n', test).strip()
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
this
is
to
learn
regex
in
python.
```

Comment: is this way to erase the "\t" using regex (re.sub("\t", "" test)

Comment: I don't understand the context in which you are asking this.  My answer already would remove `\t` tabs, and replace with just a single newline `\n`.

Comment: re.sub(r'\s+', '\n', test) is only getting one \n. there is multiple (\n\n) so how can I can get them all at one time

Comment: Now I'm just confused.  Please edit your question and tell us the real problem.  I have given you a solution which generates the output you expect.

Comment: if there is \n\n without space, the code you provide only change one \n from (\n\n) and remind there still \n. I breakpoint the code to know how it is working step by step in the visual code editor

Comment: @TulMagar: Why is replacing `\n\n` with `\n` incorrect? It's changing all runs of whitespace to a single newline; a pair (or three, or any number) of newlines *should* become a single newline. I'm not sure what else you'd expect it to do.